# Enter recovery mode (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: macos, recovery, big-sur

When holding the <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> combination on my iMac (macOS Big Sur) a command line opens but not the recovery mode window.

How to access it?

Comment: Which iMac model?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my keyboard was not a QWERTY one so I needed to hold the fourth key (which is not a R on my keyboard) for it to work.